# How do I get a list of all files in a subversion workspace ordered by last changed date/rev?

Tags: svn

I'd like to get a full inventory of files in a workspace (roughly similar to 'find .' output) ordered by the date (or revision number. . same thing) of last commit to that file.  The goal is to identify which files are most and least actively modified.  Svn info provides the relevant date but doesn't work recursively.  I have access to the svn command line client, standard *nix command line utilities, and php, though I'd prefer a one-liner to a long script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
$ svn list -v -R | sort | sort -n
```

should work.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.  Missed the -v flag on svn ls for some reason.  Also, I'm not really interested in directories, so went with "svn ls -v -R | sort -n | grep -v '/$'"